# Entity Framework Core 6 - setting the decimal precision using DBContextOptionsBuilder

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I want to set decimal precision and scale for all decimal properties in my model.
I know one of the way to do this in EF Core 6 is to override ConfigureConventions,

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(
    ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    configurationBuilder.Properties<decimal>()
        .HavePrecision(18, 6);
}
```

However, I do not have access to underlying DBContext to override or subclass it. I am using it as part of nuget package.

I have access to pass only DbContextOptionsBuilder in my application's Startup class to some method from underlying framework method which accepts parameter of type DbContextOptionsBuilder.

The underlying framework adds DbContext using AddDbContextPool method and passes DbContextOptionsBuilder received as a parameter. It is added to IServiceCollection.

```
public static void ConfigureMyAppServices(IServiceCollection services, Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> configuration)
{
services.AddDbContextPool<MyAppDbContext>(configuration);
}
```

Here MyAppDbContext inherits from DbContext.

Is there a way to plugin conventions for the entire model using DbContextOptionsBuilder object.

Comment: Well, it's possible to replace the whole model, but not sure about partial modifications. Anyway, it sounds like a weird approach to me. If you don't have access to that you are probably not eligible to modify it for a reason. Cannot imagine that other programmers plug whatever they want. Why do you want to change it? If you think that DB is wrong, ask the creator.